# What happens when a Hexed Ooze splits in two?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Many oozes have a reaction to split in two upon receiving slashing damage. If an ooze previously targeted by a Hex (or Hunter’s Mark) splits in two, what happens to the spell ?

1) Considered as if the initial target is dead (thus possible for the caster to transfer it as a bonus action to another foe)

2) Applied to both of the new oozes

3) Applied to one of the two new oozes, at random